# How to fetch images, css, js from cache (with http status 200 (cache) not 304)

Tags: javascript

I have web page which refers large number of JS, Images files. when teh page is loaded second time, 304 requests goes to the server. I would like to get http 200 (cache) status for cached object rather than 304.

I am using asp.net 4, iis 7.

Setting the Expiry header is not working, it still sends 304 requests. I want http status 200 (cache).

Please let me know if there is any technique for this.

Comment: 304 and 200 are response statuses, not types of request. 200 means "OK, here you go". 304 means "You already have the latest version, use the cache". Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you're setting the cache headers correctly, the browser won't make the request. So you'll need to read up on the correct cache headers to send, etc. If you can't get it working, **show** what you're doing (don't describe it, show the code) and people can point out what you're getting wrong.

Comment: @Quentin: I think the OP means he/she wants to avoid having the browser make any request *at all* rather than an `If-Modified-Since` request that receives a 304.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that setting the expiry doesn't help, but it does if you set the right headers.

Here's a good example: Google's library hosting. Here are the (relevant) headers Google sends back if you ask for a *fully-qualified* version of a library (e.g., jQuery 1.7.2, not jQuery 1.*, or jQuery 1.7.*):

```
Date:Thu, 07 Jun 2012 14:43:04 GMT
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Expires:Fri, 07 Jun 2013 14:43:04 GMT
```

(`Date` isn't really relevant, I just include it so you know when the headers above were generated.) There, as you can see, `Cache-Control` has been set explicitly with a `max-age` of a year, and the `Expires` header also specifies an expiration date a year from now. Subsequent access (within a year) to the same fully-qualified library doesn't even result in an `If-Modified-Since` request to the server, because the browser knows the cached copy is fresh.

[This description](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) of caching in HTTP 1.1 in RFC 2616 should help.

Comment: yes i would like to have similar behaviour for my web site. I would want, subsequent access to the same fully qualified library should not result in 304 "If-Modified-Since". Do you know if there is any Technique for this?

Comment: @user1233802: Yes: Set the headers in the response (e.g., configure your web server so it sends the correct caching headers for the documents you want treated in this way).